# Why do we get Error - Deployment did not succeed. for a react app on surge?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment, surge.sh

can anyone help me to upload a react app on surge. I am getting a Error - Deployment did not succeed.
I even tried uploading a fresh react app and I get the same error. I am using surge 
then I am adding the build path where I have changed index.js to 200.js.
After this I add the surge url something like https://es-myapp.surge.sh.
It finish's the upload process and I get 2 progress bar's with 100 % uploaded and then the Error - Deployment did not succeed.

Can anyone help me with this issue. Stuck here for quite some time.
Any help or support is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same problem...

Comment: same here.., deployment did not succeed..

Comment: I am also getting the same error message.

Comment: Do put up a comment here when its back up again! :D

Comment: Based on their twitter account, https://twitter.com/surge_sh/status/1033446417514213376, the deployment is back up and running. I confirmed that it is as well.

Comment: This was a surge problem, is working well again https://twitter.com/surge_sh/status/1042144880099639296 (this is the correct twit status not the one above)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking their service is down right now. I'm getting the same error, and so are several others from what I've seen on social media over the past few hours.